# How to calculate a moving average in python for sensor data?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, raspberry-pi, sensors

I am trying to create a simple array to collect sensor data and calculate a moving average within python.  The final result would be stored in a variable which I could publish to MQTT.  I have the code to collect the sensor data and to post it to MQTT, I just haven't figured out the bit about the array and calculating of moving averages.

I have searched for any bits of information on creating arrays and calculating moving averages but I have not found any examples of collecting data from a variable, entering that information into the array and after collecting 40 values, calculate a moving average and storing that information in a different variable.

Any advice is appreciated!

Please be gentle as I am a newbie python programmer...

```
  GNU nano 3.2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                mqtt.ph.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

#!/usr/bin/env python3



import math

import sys

import time

from grove.adc import ADC

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt # Import the MQTT library

# Our "on message" event

def messageFunction (client, userdata, message):
    topic = str(message.topic)
    message = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    print(topic + message)

ourClient = mqtt.Client("openhab_mqtt") # Create a MQTT client object
ourClient.username_pw_set(username="AAAAA",password="BBBBB")
ourClient.connect("192.168.1.XXX", XXXX) # Connect to the test MQTT broker
ourClient.subscribe("openhab") # Subscribe to the topic TDS
ourClient.on_message = messageFunction # Attach the messageFunction to subscription
ourClient.loop_start() # Start the MQTT client

# CONSTANTS

Vref = 4.95   # volts

Vcal_mv = 1903  # milli-volts (using raw value 539 * 4.95/1023 * 1000)  note 10-bit A2D

mv_per_ph = 59.6

ph_per_mv = 1.0 / mv_per_ph





class GrovePH:



    def __init__(self, channel):

        self.channel = channel

        self.adc = ADC()





    @property

    def PH(self):

        value = self.adc.read(self.channel)

        if value != 0:

            voltage_mv = value * Vref / 1023.0 * 1000

            PHValue = 7 - ((voltage_mv - Vcal_mv) * ph_per_mv)

            return PHValue

        else:

            return     


def main():



    if len(sys.argv) < 2:

        print('Usage: {} adc_channel'.format(sys.argv[0]))

        sys.exit(1)



    sensor = GrovePH(int(sys.argv[1]))

    print('Detecting PH...')



    while True:

        try:
             ourClient.publish("openhab/pH",'{:2.1f}'.format(sensor.PH)) # Publish message to MQTT broker
             time.sleep(1) # Sleep for a second

#            print('PH Value: {:2.1f}'.format(sensor.PH))

#            time.sleep(1)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:

            print("\nExiting...")

            sys.exit(0)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it easy to calculate moving average of samples by using a `deque` with a maximum number of entries in it. Then you can just keep adding samples and the length looks after itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import collections
import random

# Ensure repeatable randomness ;-)
random.seed(42)

# Define a deque with max of 40 samples
samples = collections.deque(maxlen=40)

# Add 100 random samples to deque, each one between 10..20
for i in range(100):
    # Generate random sample
    value = random.randint(10,20)
    # Append to deque
    samples.append(value)
    # Show sample, number of samples, total and moving average
    N = len(samples)
    total = sum(samples)
    movingAvg = total/N
    print(f'value: {value}, num samples: {N}, total: {total}, moving average: {movingAvg}')
```

Check the number of samples in the output below and observe that it rises to 40 but goes no higher:

**Sample Output**

```
value: 20, num samples: 1, total: 20, moving average: 20.0
value: 11, num samples: 2, total: 31, moving average: 15.5
value: 10, num samples: 3, total: 41, moving average: 13.666666666666666
value: 14, num samples: 4, total: 55, moving average: 13.75
value: 13, num samples: 5, total: 68, moving average: 13.6
value: 13, num samples: 6, total: 81, moving average: 13.5
value: 12, num samples: 7, total: 93, moving average: 13.285714285714286
value: 11, num samples: 8, total: 104, moving average: 13.0
value: 20, num samples: 9, total: 124, moving average: 13.777777777777779
value: 18, num samples: 10, total: 142, moving average: 14.2
value: 11, num samples: 11, total: 153, moving average: 13.909090909090908
value: 19, num samples: 12, total: 172, moving average: 14.333333333333334
value: 16, num samples: 13, total: 188, moving average: 14.461538461538462
value: 10, num samples: 14, total: 198, moving average: 14.142857142857142
value: 10, num samples: 15, total: 208, moving average: 13.866666666666667
value: 11, num samples: 16, total: 219, moving average: 13.6875
value: 13, num samples: 17, total: 232, moving average: 13.647058823529411
value: 13, num samples: 18, total: 245, moving average: 13.61111111111111
value: 18, num samples: 19, total: 263, moving average: 13.842105263157896
value: 19, num samples: 20, total: 282, moving average: 14.1
value: 10, num samples: 21, total: 292, moving average: 13.904761904761905
value: 18, num samples: 22, total: 310, moving average: 14.090909090909092
value: 13, num samples: 23, total: 323, moving average: 14.043478260869565
value: 20, num samples: 24, total: 343, moving average: 14.291666666666666
value: 18, num samples: 25, total: 361, moving average: 14.44
value: 16, num samples: 26, total: 377, moving average: 14.5
value: 13, num samples: 27, total: 390, moving average: 14.444444444444445
value: 17, num samples: 28, total: 407, moving average: 14.535714285714286
value: 19, num samples: 29, total: 426, moving average: 14.689655172413794
value: 14, num samples: 30, total: 440, moving average: 14.666666666666666
value: 10, num samples: 31, total: 450, moving average: 14.516129032258064
value: 12, num samples: 32, total: 462, moving average: 14.4375
value: 16, num samples: 33, total: 478, moving average: 14.484848484848484
value: 15, num samples: 34, total: 493, moving average: 14.5
value: 14, num samples: 35, total: 507, moving average: 14.485714285714286
value: 12, num samples: 36, total: 519, moving average: 14.416666666666666
value: 13, num samples: 37, total: 532, moving average: 14.378378378378379
value: 15, num samples: 38, total: 547, moving average: 14.394736842105264
value: 11, num samples: 39, total: 558, moving average: 14.307692307692308
value: 11, num samples: 40, total: 569, moving average: 14.225
value: 16, num samples: 40, total: 565, moving average: 14.125
value: 11, num samples: 40, total: 565, moving average: 14.125
value: 15, num samples: 40, total: 570, moving average: 14.25
value: 15, num samples: 40, total: 571, moving average: 14.275
```

---

For the purists, I agree it is probably more efficient to keep my variable `total` as a *running total of last N samples*, and subtract the 41st oldest sample from the total as it leaves the window of interesting samples. That way you can avoid having to run `sum(samples)` on every iteration. But for small window sizes and non performance-critical uses, the suggested method definitely has the benefit of simplicity.

**Keywords**: Python, moving average, duque, fixed length, maximum length, window, windowed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to calculate moving averages using plain Python.

You may change the time window by changing the value in the `window` variable. For example, if you wanted a 30 minute time window, you would change the number to 3000000000.

In this example, the entries are saved in a dictionary named `data`. However, you may choose the data source that makes sense to you. The most important thing is that each entry within the collection has a timestamp with microseconds.

```
data = {}

def one_minute_averages():
    window = int(datetime.now().strftime("%H%M%S%f")) - 100000000
    history = {}
    for i in message_log.items():
        if i[0] >= window:
            history.update({i})
    for i in list(history):
        if i < window:
            history.pop(i)
    avg = sum(history.values()) / len(list(history))
    return avg
```

Note: You may want to add some error handling to avoid division by zero or if the function can't access your data.

I welcome you to comment :)